# QGIS failing to include Authorization header (WMS layers)

Tags: qgis, wms, http

QGIS 3.16.1-Hannover

QGIS is attempting to authenticate with GeoServer using OAuth2.

Authentication is configured as such:

[image]

For **WFS** it works perfectly. Note that it even specifies where in the cpp file the network request was made.

[image]

For **WMS** however, the Authorization code is not added, leading to a 403 response. Note that, this time, the Initiator/ID does not mention the cpp file, it says 'unknown', which could be a sign the cpp wms provider plugin is faulty?

[image]

Any guidance on this?

Comment: Try a newer QGIS version and see if the error persists. There apparently was work on the Oauth2 code recently, see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/46354 . Try a very new version of qgis.

Comment: Problem is, I’m running it on a M1 chip. Apparently this is the latest version that runs on M1?

Comment: Here https://www.reddit.com/r/QGIS/comments/up1tkc/what_is_the_current_state_of_qgis_on_the_m1_chip/ a redditor states he is using 3.24 on a M1 . I don't have experience with Macs or M1 and QGIS.

Comment: Update: tried it on both 3.22 and 3.24 on M1 and it's still not working